# Unable to generate route for logout

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I had just syntax problem(I belive), which stop me for doing my next steps. 
So I want to make a login system, and when one of session attr is set, the button on template will change for 'logout' with route to logout user.
Apparently my template doesn't load because:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "logout" as such route
>   does not exist.").

Here's my code of logoutAction

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render("/login/register.html.twig");
}
```

And template

```
{%  if app.session.get('username') %}
                <a href="{{ path('logout') }}">
                <button type="button" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-primary">Wyloguj</button>
                </a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path('login_route') }}">
                    <button type="button" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-primary">Logowanie</button>
                </a>
            {% endif %}
```

And for debug purposes using of debug:router command:

```
>  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
>  -------------------------- -------- -------- ------
> -----------------------------------    _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                         _profiler_home  
> ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                          
> _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                     _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar                 _profiler_info             ANY  
> ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}              
> _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                    _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results     _profiler_open_file        ANY  
> ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                       _profiler       
> ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                   
> _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router             _profiler_exception        ANY  
> ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception         
> _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css      _twig_error_test           ANY  
> ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}              homepage        
> ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                    
> produkty                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /produkty         
> login_route                ANY      ANY      ANY    /login            
> login_check                ANY      ANY      ANY    /login_check      
> register                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /register         
> create                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /create           
> logout                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /logout           
> -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

Comment: Make sure to clear your cache (`cache:clear --env=... [--no-debug]`) or that your website actually runs in the same environment as you use for your `router:debug` command - which is probably `dev`.

Comment: Yeah... cache:clear --env=dev works for me and solve the problem. Thanks for help buddy